# How do I publish private app on Google play with or without Android Management API?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-management-api, emm

I am able to build a small EMM project using new android management APIs. My use case is dedicated users device management, where we manage both hardware and the apps for our clients. All the app updates part I have been reading is using public apps or the private apps where the client will update on their device. But In our case we want up load a private app  and  provide updates programmatically. I have tested public app from google play store and it works fine with device policy controller. How do I access my private apps ? Also most of the documentation you see is for device admin Management related where google used to host the EMM . I am looking for the latest Android Management API solution where there is no console and we have to build one.

**Update**:
I am able to private publish to managed google console using this link
https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/9146439

But when I apply (DPC)device policy controller to install this app .it is not happening. I tested with one of our own public apps using DPC and it installs and uninstalls instantly . Any one knows where am I going wrong ?

Any help is appreciated ....

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

Comment: I am able to create the private app but I am unable to install it using the policy manager

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your private app is distributed to your enterprise. You can check this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/9495634?hl=en#) to know more about distributing your private app to an enterprise. You can also use check this [ApplicationPolicy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#ApplicationPolicy) which can push apps as part of the enterprise policy.